# Partial VPN connectivity

Tags: private-network

I use a Juniper VPN to connect to my office remotely from home. However, i also want to connect to a 3rd network, and my office network does not have the network capacity to handle the thru-put of the 3rd network.

So, i'd like to use my current VPN to maintain my remote office connection, but NOT use the VPN to connect to a 3rd remote network simultaneously. How do i do this?

Currently, when i connect to my office VPN...all my networking traffic is routed thru my office's network (this is the standard of how a VPN operates as far as i know).

What can i do to limit which traffic goes over the VPN (i only have 3-4 applications that require my office VPN)?

my home machine is Windows 7. I'm wondering if i run the XP Virtual machine on my Win7 box, and then establish the VPN to my office from inside the XP virtual machine to my office...will my main Windows 7 machine also be accessing the VPN...or would i be free to use my standard home network?

Answer (score 0):

The name for what you are trying to do is called "split tunnelling".

In your case, however, this is not recommended. The VPN to your office is there for a reason - to keep the office systems and network safe. The whole purpose is to disconnect you from any other network and force all traffic via the VPN. Doing anything else would compromise the office network. If that belongs to your business (assuming you don't own the business), you will almost certainly be breaking the terms of service. You might well find yourself being hauled in for a serious talking to. Indeed, if it resulted in an actual compromise, you would be fired with no comeback.

Fix your office network by adding suitable connections, security and bandwidth.

A virtual machine doesn't really help as the tunnel is formed by the host PC. The only way would be to run BOTH VPN's from separate VM's so that the host is not constrained by a VPN.

You could talk to your office IT to ask if split tunnelling is allowed and whether they can configure the Juniper to allow it but I doubt they would be willing.

You might be able to use a remote desktop on one of the networks which might also help control the bandwidth.